# how to assign future<> to widget in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Suppose I have a `SingleChildScrollView`, its content is read from a file:

```
singleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: nw Text(
          getTextFromFile(), //<---read from file
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 19.0,
          ),
        ));

  Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
  }

  Future<String> getTextFromFile() async {
      return getFileData("test.txt");
  }
```

I got the following error:

```
The argument type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter
type 'String'.
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: You'll probably need a FutureBuilder around that.

Comment: I think the answer with the FutureBuilder should be the chosen one. Simpler & recommended by Flutter.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[`StatefulWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) can be used for this purpose. 
Declare a member variable `String _textFromFile = ""`; in your State class and update its value on future resolve by using [`setState()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) method.

I called your `getTextFromFile()` method from the constructor, but you may call it from anywhere.

Running code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class StatefullWidgetDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StatefulWidgetDemoState createState() {
    return new _StatefulWidgetDemoState();
  }
}

class _StatefulWidgetDemoState extends State<StatefullWidgetDemo> {
  String _textFromFile = "";

  _StatefulWidgetDemoState() {
    getTextFromFile().then((val) => setState(() {
          _textFromFile = val;
        }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Stateful Demo'),
      ),
      body: new SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: new Text(
          _textFromFile,
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 19.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
    return "your data from file";
  }

  Future<String> getTextFromFile() async {
    return await getFileData("test.txt");
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems more intuitive, so I mark it as accepted. I also like the answer Doge, So I vote it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Just to add on, the [Flutter Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) recommend adding the fetch in `initState()`.

Answer (score 65):

Using a FutureBuilder should solve your problem. I modified you code so you can see how to use it. `initialData` is not required.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FutureBuilder(
      future: getTextFromFile(),
      initialData: "Loading text..",
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> text) {
        return new SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: new Text(
            text.data,
            style: new TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 19.0,
            ),
          ));
      });
  }

  Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
    return await new Future(() => "test text");
  }

  Future<String> getTextFromFile() async {
    return getFileData("test.txt");
  }
}
```

Comment: but this method is too big to achive simple things

Comment: @Bensal i don't think so, if you see it well it is just the first four lines of code after return because the answer includes the details of implementation of the full component. I think if your plan is to use the future response in a component this is just awesome. In four lines of code i have full control over the async thing. No try, catch or then catch complications, just simple piece of code

Comment: I believe that this is the right method to go and should have been the accepted answer. Future and Stream are some of the most highlighted features of Dart and flutter gives FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder to work with this data types. I would avoid using .then() method while working with Flutter.

Comment: Surprised that this is not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

Simple answer here=>

The class which calls the function:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
 child: FutureBuilder(
  future: function(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> text) {
    return new Text(text.data);
  });
)}
```

And the function:

```
Future<String> function() async {
   return 'abc';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar question:

[flutter / dart error: The argument type 'Future<File>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49854024/flutter-dart-error-the-argument-type-futurefile-cant-be-assigned-to-the)

The solution proposed there is quite elegant and works properly. Where the IDE says it's expecting `Type` and not `Future<Type>`, put `await` in front of that argument

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to get data on initialization would be to call `getTextFromFile()` in `initState()`, set state with new string and use that string in your widget:

```
String fileData = '';

Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
  }

void getTextFromFile() async {
    try {
      String data = await getFileData("test.txt");
      setState(() {
        fileData = data;
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      print(ex);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTextFromFile();
  }

new singleChildScrollView(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: new Text(
          fileData,
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 19.0,
          ),
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more answer, as I tested other answers I got an error.
Moving the async part (plus setState) from the constructor to `initState()` solved that for me.

Enjoy

```dart
class TestAsyncInStateful extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestAsyncInStateful({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestAsyncInStateful> createState() => _TestAsyncInStatefulState();
}

class _TestAsyncInStatefulState extends State<TestAsyncInStateful> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getTextFromServer().then(
      (value) => setState(() {
        textFromServer = value;
      }),
    );
  }

  String? textFromServer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return textFromServer == null? const SizedBox() :Text(textFromServer!);
  }
}
```