# Using Futurebuilder to render widgets conditionally

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and Dart. So I'm trying to build a simple authentication system in Flutter. When the User opens the app, I want to either show them the `LoginScreen` (where they had not previously logged in) or the `HomeScreen` when they are logged in.

`loadWidget`, which returns a `Future` would determine whether there is persistent data and hence fetches the user's info and displays the Home Screen. The child property would not let me assign a Future to it, I'm not sure but I suppose I would have to use FutureBuilder widget for this?

**First Try**

```
  Future<Widget> loadWidget() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // already logged in
    String phone = prefs.getString('phoneNumber');
    if (phone != null) {     
      helper.user = await checkUser(phone); // fetch user info
      return HomeScreen();
    }
    // Not logged in
    else {
      return Login();
    }
  }
```

For the build function, this does not work

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: loadWidget(), // This does not allow me to assign a future
    )
);
  }
```

**Second Try: Using the FutureBuilder** 
 
I read about Futurebuilder here [how to assign future<> to widget in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49764905/how-to-assign-future-to-widget-in-flutter) and it looks like the way to go, so I modified my build method as

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: loadWidget(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> widget){
            return widget;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But this gave me the following error:

> The return type 'AsyncSnapshot' isn't a 'Widget', as defined
>   by anonymous closure.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it right but the problem is with the returning object from the FutureBuilder, see the comments in this code:

```dart
// *NOTE: build return Widget: Widget build...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: loadWidget(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> widget){
            // But 'widget' here is NOT a widget, it is an AsyncSnapshot object,
            // return widget; // **is wrong**
            // instead:
            return widget.data;

            // and better to make it like this:
            //if (!widget.hasData) {
            //  return Center(
            //    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            //  );
            //}
            //return widget.data;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

that was to fix the error. An extra advice for cleaner code, keep your Authentication layer(loadWidget) clean by making it return only state(Auth or Not), then catch the state using `widget.data` inside the `FutureBuilder`, and then route based on the Auth-state from inside the `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: This worked. Also, thanks for the advice, will keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

I would move the future into the FutureBuilder and then put the logic inside it

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: loadWidget(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> sharedPreference) {
              String phone = sharedPreference.getString('phoneNumber');
              if (phone != null) {
                return HomeScreen();
              }
              // Not logged in
              else {
                return Login();
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```